# JavaScript/ Service worker/ Web worker: Will closing tab, clear my global data?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, service-worker

I am trying to implement **undo** functionality on my portal. The user has an undo option for 10 sec. After that a request will be made to the server to make the desire changes.

Steps:

1. On Button click I will storing the value in an JavaScript array. The array structure would be like 
     0=>{
           id => time_of_storage
        }
     1=>{
           id => time_of_storage
        }
     2=>{
           id => time_of_storage
        }....
2. I want a background service that will fetch values from this array which are older than 1 min and make an ajax call to my server.

Two of my concerns

1. Data should not be lost on tab close.
2. How to implement this?

Comment: I would ether store it in a cookie or use a Javascript database like TaffyDB or couchDB.

Comment: I'm not sure if closing the tab will clear global data though, it makes since it would

Comment: When the tab is closed, everything is gone except if stored somewhere persistent such as local storage. What do you mean by "global data"?

Comment: Global data here means that an array which will get populated by various functions.